# C - "Segmentation fault: 11" running program

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

This program returns "Segmentation fault: 11" when I run it. The compiler (GCC) doesn't return any error or warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char day[3];
  char month[3];
  char year[5];
} DATA;

DATA *data;

int main()
{
  FILE *file;
  char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];

  if (!(file = fopen("file.dat", "rt")))
  { 
    printf ("Something went wrong while opening the file.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    int line_number = 0;

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), file))
    {
      ++line_number;

      if      (line_number == 1) { strncpy(data->day,   line_buffer, 2); }
      else if (line_number == 2) { strncpy(data->month, line_buffer, 2); }
      else if (line_number == 3) { strncpy(data->year,  line_buffer, 4); }
    }

    printf("Content: %s-%s-%s\n", data->day, data->month, data->year); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The content of file.dat is:

```
12
08
1990
```

I've debugged it with GDB and this is the result:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/macuser/Desktop/Primitiva/Proyecto/a.out
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff949413a0 in _dispatch_queue_attrs () from /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
```

What does that mean and what can I do to solve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that while using `malloc` would work, it's unecessary extra work for you since you will also have to call `free` later when you no longer need to use the `data` struct. But for that you should make the variable local to `main()`.

This should solve your problem

```
typedef struct {
char day[3];
char month[3];
char year[5];
} DATA;

DATA data;
/*  ^ no star here, because you don't need a pointer in your particular case */

int main()
{
FILE *file;
char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];

if (!(file = fopen("file.dat", "rt")))
{
    printf ("Something went wrong while opening the file.\n");
}
else
{
    int line_number = 0;

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), file))
    {
    ++line_number;

    if      (line_number == 1) { strncpy(data.day,   line_buffer, 2); }
    else if (line_number == 2) { strncpy(data.month, line_buffer, 2); }
    else if (line_number == 3) { strncpy(data.year,  line_buffer, 4); }
    }

    printf("Content: %s-%s-%s\n", data.day, data.month, data.year);
}
return 0;
}
```

You don't need to declare `data` as a pointer in this particular case, and it would be better if you don't until you understand dynamic memory allocation correctly, also, the `data` variable does not need to be global, you can declare it inside the `main()` function.

The segmentation fault is caused by an invalid pointer dereference, if you want to use a pointer then this is how you should do it

```
typedef struct {
char day[3];
char month[3];
char year[5];
} DATA;

int main()
{
FILE *file;
char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];
if (!(file = fopen("file.dat", "rt")))
{
    printf ("Something went wrong while opening the file.\n");
}
else
{
    int line_number = 0;
    DATA *data;

    /* 
     * here data is an invalid pointer, it points nowhere. 
     * to make it valid you need malloc
     */
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    /* on failure, malloc returns NULL, for example when there is no more memory left in the system 
     * so one should check for the return value
     */
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return -1;
    }
    /* now data is a valid pointer you can derefrence it */

    while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), file))
    {
    ++line_number;

    if      (line_number == 1) { strncpy(data->day,   line_buffer, 2); }
    else if (line_number == 2) { strncpy(data->month, line_buffer, 2); }
    else if (line_number == 3) { strncpy(data->year,  line_buffer, 4); }
    }

    printf("Content: %s-%s-%s\n", data->day, data->month, data->year);
    /* after you have finished using the pointer, call free */
    free(data);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked! But what's the difference between use the pointer or not to have a segmentation fault?

Comment: @mariec I don't understand your question.

Comment: @mariec, I updated the answer with a pointer version of the program, check the source, it has comments to let you know how it works.

Comment: Yes, I've only changed the pointer and now the program works, and that's because some difference exists having a pointer that makes it go outside the memory restriction for the program. It's just curiosity, that would be hard stuff I guess haha

Comment: @mariec it's not hard, you just need to read about it, and what you had in your code is called undefined behavior, because you was dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate memory to your structure

```
DATA *data = malloc(sizeof(DATA));
```

You should allocate memory to your pointer before writing something to it.

Comment: This is not gonna compile if the OP naively puts the `malloc` in his source code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry I didn't get you. Allocating memory is the reason he is seeing a crash

Comment: That's true, but you cannot call `malloc` (or any other function) to initialize a **global** variable.

Comment: Michael is right. The compiler returns: `main.c:11:14: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
DATA *data = malloc(sizeof(DATA));
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.`

Comment: Yes yea yes. The answer is mainly to suggest allocating memory.

Comment: Ok that works when in the code after `DATA *data` I put: `data = malloc(sizeof(*data));`